# Shortcut Commandfile Commandline-Parameter Win7 more than one value

Tags: windows, shell, command-line, cmd, shortcut

I know how to set commandline parameters for shortcuts to cmd files, by modifying a target-shortcut property.

```
"C:\test\cT.cmd" -logpk cur -lp c:\xxx\testlogs
```

But how can i feed more than one argument values to an argument point

```
C:\test\cT.cmd -logpk cur -lp c:\xxx\testlogs -s 22.07.2014 14:30:00
```

The thing above works as cmd command but if i add it to a shortcut target the "-s" option is not filled by the cmd properly.

```
"C:\test\cT.cmd" -logpk cur -lp c:\xxx\testlogs -s 22.07.2014 14:30:00
```

[image: PropertieShortcut]

Maybe you know how to split "morenode arguments" so they can be used for shortcuts too.

best regards

EDIT:

```
if "%argument%" == "-s" ( 
    set startDay=%argumentValueOne%
    set startTime=%argumentValueTwo%
    if "%argumentValueOne%" == "a" set startDay=""
    if "%argumentValueTwo%" == "A" set startTime=""
    set startDate=-s %startDay% %startTime% 
    echo startDate %startDate%
    shift 
    shift
    shift
    goto validate
)
```

EDIT2:

```
C:\test\>
if "-s" == "-s" (
set startDay=22.07.2014
 set startTime=14:30:00
 if "22.07.2014" == "a" set startDay=""
 if "14:30:00" == "A" set startTime=""
 set startDate=-s
 echo startDate
 shift
 shift
 shift
 goto validate
)

-s    -logpk cur -vendor -lp c:\xxx\testlogs
```

If called from cmd shortcut

EDIT3:

```
C:\test\>
if "-s" == "-s" (
set startDay=22.07.2014
 set startTime=14:30:00
 if "22.07.2014" == "a" set startDay=""
 if "14:30:00" == "A" set startTime=""
 set startDate=-s 22.07.2014 14:30:00
 echo startDate -s 22.07.2014 14:30:00
 shift
 shift
 shift
 goto validate
)

-s 22.07.2014 14:30:00 -logpk cur -vendor -lp c:\xxx\testlogs
```

If called from opened cmd

Comment: What do you mean it's not filled with cmd properly? Also what do you mean by split morenode arguments?

Comment: The cmd script doesn't recognize it as valid argument. I want to know if there is maybe a way with delimeters like ",/,... to split 22.07.2014 14:30:00 for proper function and recognization of the arguments

Comment: This works the way it should right? `C:\test\cT.cmd -logpk cur -lp c:\xxx\testlogs -s 22.07.2014 14:30:00`. It just doesn't work when placed on a shortcut. Is it correct?

Comment: yes, the normal command, executed by opening a cmd before, works like charm

Comment: Can you try `"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" /c C:\test\cT.cmd -logpk cur -lp c:\xxx\testlogs -s 22.07.2014 14:30:00` in the shortcut?

Comment: this also leaves the -s parameter empty or not recognized:-/

Comment: Try removing the `@echo off` line and post back the output..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are running into the infamous early variable expansion problem. your variables are replaced with their values at the start of the block. since at that time startday and starttime are empty, this is what you get.
i suspect that in your testing from the command line, the variables are already set from the first try (they remain in the environment, you can see it with `set`).
the way around that is putting `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` at the beginning of your batch file, and then reference your variables with `!startday!` instead of `%startday%`.

Comment: genius :) I was wondering why I sometimes had to start it two times